# Bootstrap vertical grid with mix of fixed and aligned content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap grid/row that looks like this...

```
<!--column a-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
</div>

<!--column b-->
<div class="col-sm-6"> 

    <!-- I want this div to always be fixed at the top of column b and take up 15% of column b's height-->
    <div>
        <h1 id="mainText">
            Some main text
        </h1>
    </div>

    <!-- I want these 2 divs to be centered within the remaining 85% of column b's height-->
    <div>
        <p id="bodyText">
            Some body text
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 id="detailText">
            Some detail text
        </h2>
    </div>

</div>

<!--column c-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
</div>
```

I want the top div within column b (that contains the h1 element "mainText"), to always be fixed at the top - accounting for, say the top 15% of the column.

I then want the remaining 2 divs (containing "bodyText" and "detailText") to be vertically centered/spread-out within the remaining 85% of column B.

I can achieve the vertical center effect on all 3 divs within col-sm-6 by simply adding "margin:auto" to col-sm-6 (but of course this means "mainText" might slip down further than 15% of column B).  So I experimented adding another div (with "margin:auto") around the last 2 divs, but it had no effect at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to combine these 2 requirements of fixing one div within a bootstrap column, and spreading out the other 2?  Really struggling to visualise the right way to structure this so appreciate any thoughts at all.

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is to give `mainText` `height: 15%` and then wrap the other two divs in a `flex` container. If you need older browser support, then perhaps do the same but instead of a `flex` container, have a normal div with `height: 85%`, then give `bodyText` and `detailText` inside it `height: 50%` each

Comment: Thanks Mike - I like the last solution but the problem is that I can't define the absolute height of col-sm-6 in advance (and I also can't just set every one of the parent elements to height:100% all the way back up to body/html).  Experimenting with various flexbox solutions now.